# How to reindex a spesific column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, series, reindex

```
gd = df.groupby(['subID'])['Accuracy'].std()

print(gd)

subID
4       0.810423
5       0.841364
6       0.881007
8       0.763175
9       0.760102
10      0.905283
12      0.928358
14      0.779291
15      0.912377
1018    0.926683
```

It displays like this and I assume it is a Series, not a DataFrame. I want to change the last index from 1018 to 13.

Comment: when you want the index to start from 0 to the maximum number you can also consider `gd = gd.reset_index()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rename` with dictionary, because first column here is `index` of `Series`:

```
gd = gd.rename({1018:13})
```

Working like:

```
gd = gd.rename(index={1018:13})
```